# I would like to warp a token and inherit its methods in a wrapper without declaring them in a wrapper. Can I do this?

Tags: tokens

The reason why I am asking this is to create something that is closely related to mutability. So, instead of creating a different token every time there is a code-change, I would like to simply use a wrapper and then wrap another token/contract that has the updated code.

Was anything like this done before, and if yes, where can I learn more about this approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with proxy pattern and `delegatecall` opcode.

Check this article from openzeppelin https://blog.openzeppelin.com/proxy-patterns/

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, thank you!